# What happens to my cards exiled by an opponent's Oblivion Ring when they lose the game?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-multiplayer

My opponent in a multiplayer game had exiled 2 cards I controlled during a recent game with an [Oblivion Ring](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOblivion%20Ring%5d) like ability.  On my next turn I hit him for lethal.

What happens when he loses the game? Do the 2 cards remain exiled or do they re-enter play under my control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Permanents exiled by [Oblivion Ring](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOblivion%20Ring%5d) stay exiled when its controller loses. To quote Ask a Magic Judge from [March 16th 2018](https://magicjudge.tumblr.com/post/171909854642/in-multiplayer-if-a-card-is-banished-with-a-card):

> **deg99 asked:** In multiplayer, if a card is banished with a card like Oblivon ring, and oblivion ring's controller loses, is the banished card returned to play?
>
> **Judge:** No because the separate return trigger never gets to go on the stack.

This is because a player who's lost can't put any abilities on the stack—they're no longer in the game. From [the multiplayer rules](https://blogs.magicjudges.org/rules/cr800/#4d) (where “an object” includes things like triggered abilities):

> **800.4d** If an object that would be owned by a player who has left the game would be created in any zone, it isn’t created. If a triggered ability that would be controlled by a player who has left the game would be put onto the stack, it isn’t put on the stack.

(We can also reference [March 30th 2013](https://magicjudge.tumblr.com/post/46633297693/if-a-player-loses-and-had-an-oblivion-ring) for this situation.)

The answer is different if Oblivion Ring's *owner* loses, but they weren't controlling the Ring at the time. Suppose Player A cast the Ring, and later Player B gains control of it. When Player A loses the game, their Oblivion Ring also leaves, and the exiled cards *will* come back. Quoting the judge again from [March 14th 2015](https://magicjudge.tumblr.com/post/113603835269/what-happens-when-the-owner-of-an-oblivion-ring):

> **mightym79 asked:** What happens when the owner of an Oblivion Ring loses in a multiplayer game while another player controls it (e.g. because of Zedruu giving it away)? Does the permanent come back?
>
> **Judge:** Because Oblivion Ring’s controller is still in the game, the “leaves the battlefield” ability will trigger and resolve as normal, returning whatever was exiled.

---

This situation is entirely because Oblivion Ring has a separate triggered ability that returns the permanent. This will occur the same way with any other permanent meeting that pattern, such as [Detention Sphere](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDetention%20Sphere%5d) or [Fiend Hunter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFiend%20Hunter%5d).

If instead your permanents are exiled with [Banisher Priest](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBanisher%20Priest%5d), [Banishing Light](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBanishing%20Light%5d), or any other card which says approximately “exile those cards until this permanent leaves the battlefield”, your permanents *will* return as the Banisher Priest leaves the battlefield. This is because the effect keeping them exiled simply ends.